# How do I parse a JProperty to retreive nested values with variable keys

Tags: c#, json

Given I have a JObject:

```
{
    "results": {
        "payroll_report": {
            "314568": {
                "user_id": 314568,
                "client_id": "484781",
                "start_date": "2020-03-29",
                "end_date": "2020-04-04",
                "total_re_seconds": 49260,
                "total_pto_seconds": 94716,
                "total_work_seconds": 143976,
                "total_paid_break_seconds": 0,
                "total_unpaid_break_seconds": 0,
                "pto_seconds": {
                    "22322828": 57348,
                    "12597955": 37368
                },
                "total_ot_seconds": 0,
                "total_dt_seconds": 0,
                "timesheet_count": 16
            }
        }
    },
}
```

How do I parse it so I can know the number of pto_seconds for 22322828?

I am already able to get total_pro_seconds and other elements at that level, but I can't figure out how to get the nested values.

Comment: I'd expect you to be able to just cast the value of the property to another `JObject`.

Comment: Sometimes, the object comes back like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate over JObject, (if your initial JObject is named jObject)

```
var toEnumerate = (JObject)(jObject["results"]["payroll_report"]["314568"]["pto_seconds"]);

foreach(var pair in toEnumerate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + pair.Value);
}
```

output:

```
Key: 22322828
Value: 57348
Key: 12597955
Value: 37368
```

Comment: Sometimes, the object comes back like:
```{
    "results": {
        "payroll_report": []
    }
}```

When that happens, it blows up the method trying to enumerate it. What is the best way to test for that condition?

Comment: @BrianMyrick: Please try to turning a question into a game of hide-and-seek, where we find the solution to the currently-stated problem, only to be told "Oh, but actually sometimes it's like this" - which can happen multiple times. Put **all** the relevant information in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't know that would be a problem until I tried it. I was able to figure it out, I marked the question answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is you want to access all the nested Key-Value pairs under the pto_seconds element and assume that json structure is always as it was given on the example.

Here is the full code to iterate over the list and get values. My second assumption is values are `long` type, that is why I used `jToken.First().Value<long>()`. If it is `decimal` or other types you can change it accordingly.

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var jTokenList = jObject["results"]["payroll_report"]["314568"]["pto_seconds"].Children().ToList();
foreach (var jToken in jTokenList)
{
    var ptoSecondKey = (jToken as JProperty).Name;
    var ptoSecondValue = jToken.First().Value<long>();
}
```

**Alternative method(without using JObject):**
You can have real object representation of your JSON structure and you can use `DeserializeObject<T>` method to parse and return results as your object.

Here below you can find classes for your JSON:

```
public class ResultsMain
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public ResultsDetail Results { get; set; }
}

public class ResultsDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("payroll_report")]
    public PayrollReport PayrollReport { get; set; }
}

public class PayrollReport
{
    [JsonProperty("314568")]
    public PayrollReportDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class PayrollReportDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("pto_seconds")]
    public Dictionary<string, long>  PtoSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize the JSON to your .NET type, you need below one line of code:

```
var resultsMain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultsMain>(json);
```

Here is a snapshot of resultMain object:
[image: pto_seconds values in debug mode]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue. See below 2 options are

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var results = jObject["results"];
        var payroll_report = results["payroll_report"];
        var user314568 = payroll_report["314568"];
        var total_pto_seconds = user314568["total_pto_seconds"];
        var pto_seconds = user314568["pto_seconds"];
        ///**************option1***********************
        var val1 = pto_seconds["22322828"];
        var val2 = pto_seconds["12597955"];

        Console.WriteLine($"22322828: {val1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"22322828: {val2}");

        ///**************option2***********************
        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(pto_seconds.ToString());
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[image]